# array wordpress when get is null

Tags: php, query

I've set this code to manage filters from a page list of posts in wordpress.
This filter run if I have all the variables not null, like this: ?TYPE=Apartment&AREA=Chianti&PRICE=A

but when one of them are empty, code give me an empty result.
How can I fix?

```php
if(isset($type_search) OR isset($area_search)  OR isset($prezzo_search)) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'villa_type_buy',
                    'value'     => $type_search,
                    'compare'   => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'Area',
                    'value'     => $area_search,
                    'compare'   => '='
                )
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'price_buy',
                'value'     => array( $start_price, $end_price ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN'
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to build up the query differently depending on which arguments have values or not.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use PHP function [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and the [`AND / &&`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operator to build your `if` check to be certain that all of the required parameters are present.

```
if (
    ! empty( $type_search ) &&
    ! empty( $area_search ) &&
    ! empty( $prezzo_search ) &&
) {

    // your ocde
    
}
```

*P.s. type and area could be an excellent opportunity to use custom taxonomies and terms instead of post meta, if they can only have one or more predifned values and they are used to group posts together. Using custom taxonomies can provide you better performance, more on this for example here, https://tomjn.com/2016/12/05/post-meta-abuse/ (not written by me).*